# Rewrite outgoing mail subject to specific alias

Tags: postfix

I've created an alias group in Postfix (using webmin, fyi) but I also want it to prepend something to the subject. Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to clarify to make sure I understand, you want to have a fixed subject prefix for every outgoing email that comes from a particular alias?

There are 2 things which come to mind, the former being a quick push in probably the wrong direction and the latter being a little bit more informed and accurate ;)

1. http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html
2. The postfix config file master.cf allows you to do whatever you want with the email as it traverses through.  You could write a script that does the transformation you want and pipe the email through it using master.cf.  The script would have to make sure to leave the email in correct format though, so I probably would never do this for fear of screwing up the email.  Something like altermime (http://www.pldaniels.com/altermime/) would be safer if you go down this route, rather than reinventing the wheel.  I haven't used it but it is fairly well-used and so probably more reliable than a DIY approach.

Good luck